# failure to stat /proc/self/map_files symlink - permission denied?

Tags: linux, permissions, proc

I am writing some code that checksums executable mappings. Through /proc/$PID/map_files, Linux provides symlinks to the files that back memory mappings.

My code is calling "stat()" on one of these symlinks (corresponding to the main executable) and unfortunately gets "permission denied".

I can reproduce this using regular command line tools:

```
thomasdullien@debian-laptop:~$ stat /proc/1518/map_files/400000-514000
  File: /proc/1518/map_files/400000-514000 -> /tmp/go-build362981811/b001/hashcache.test
  Size: 64          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   symbolic link
Device: 4h/4d   Inode: 4248433     Links: 1
Access: (0400/lr--------)  Uid: ( 1000/thomasdullien)   Gid: ( 1000/thomasdullien)
Access: 2020-05-23 10:03:58.510445910 +0200
Modify: 2020-05-23 10:03:58.510445910 +0200
Change: 2020-05-23 10:03:58.510445910 +0200
 Birth: -
thomasdullien@debian-laptop:~$ stat -L /proc/1518/map_files/400000-514000
stat: cannot stat '/proc/1518/map_files/400000-514000': Operation not permitted
thomasdullien@debian-laptop:~$ stat /tmp/go-build362981811/b001/hashcache.test
  File: /tmp/go-build362981811/b001/hashcache.test
  Size: 2543616     Blocks: 4968       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 41425437    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/thomasdullien)   Gid: ( 1000/thomasdullien)
Access: 2020-05-23 10:03:58.482452052 +0200
Modify: 2020-05-23 10:03:58.478452928 +0200
Change: 2020-05-23 10:03:58.478452928 +0200
 Birth: -
```

So I can lstat the original symlink, I can stat the target file, but regular stat on the symlink fails. I guess the problem is related to the following section of the man page:

```
No permissions are required on the file itself,  but—in the  case of stat(),
fstatat(), and lstat()—execute (search) permission is required on all of the
directories in  pathname  that  lead  to  the file.
```

It seems that /proc/$PID/map_files/ itself is not +x, so the process does not have the permissions to stat any of these symlinks?

Is that the case? Does anyone have an explanation why the permissions would be set like that?

Is there a way for the a process to stat these symlinks as non-root?